# Get Java Applets working offline

Tags: java, applet, offline, html5-appcache, offlineapps

I have a web page that needs to be able to work while offline. I have been able to mostly get this to work using the appcache manifest. But it also has a Java applet which doesn't seem to be working while offline. If the internet drops out after the page has loaded it works fine. If you then refresh the page it still works. But if you close the browser and reopen the browser and page while offline the Java applet fails to load giving the error main.class not found. The declaration for the applet is:

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" class="appshow" id="appobj">
        <param name="archive" value="smain.jar, splugin.jar">
        <param name="code" value="main.class">
</object>
```

I have included smain.jar, splugin.jar and main.class in the appcache file, but it appears that it is trying to fetch these from the server and not from the appcache. I also tried putting the jar and class files in cache_archive and also cache_archive_ex, but that didn't work either. How can I get the applet to load while offline?

Comment: You'll probably need to switch to JWS for this.